# Prove the convergence of $\sum_{i=3}^\infty \ln(1- \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \ln i})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

As part of the question that I'm solving, I need to prove the convergence of the sum $$\sum_{i=3}^\infty \ln(1- \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \ln i})$$
I feel that 1 possible way of approaching the problem is using the Taylor expansion of $\ln (1-x)$, $$\ln (1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
which will give us $$\ln(1- \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \log i})=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} (\frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{i \ln i})^n$$
But I don't know how to continue from here. Any help is appreciated,
thanks in advance!

Edit: changed from $\sum_{i=2}^\infty \ln(1- \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \ln i})$ to $\sum_{i=3}^\infty \ln(1- \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \ln i})$, since otherwise the argument to \ln can be negative.

Comment: The Taylor expansion is a good idea—indeed, probably the linear inequalities $-x \ge \log(1-x) \ge -2x$ for $0\le x\le\frac34$ are enough to determine convergence or divergence. Are you sure that the sum converges? (Note also that the $i=2$ term is undefined, as it's the logarithm of a negative number.)

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't notice that. I can just make $i$ start from 3. Where $i$ starts is adjustable in my problem!

Comment: You can't prove that, because it is wrong.

Comment: Could you please tell me why is it so?

Comment: $\ln(1- \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \ln i})\le-\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i \ln i}$, and both $\sum^\infty_{i=3}\frac{1}{i}$ and $\sum^\infty_{i=3}\frac{1}{i \ln i}$ diverge.

Comment: Ok, thank you! When you put it like this it's quite obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

You just need the limit comparison test:

$$\ln(1-X)\sim -X \;(X\to 0)$$

So,

$$\ln\Bigl(1-\frac 1i-\frac{1}{i\ln(i)}\Bigr)$$
$$\sim \frac{- 1}{i}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{\ln(i)}\Bigr)$$

$$\sim \frac{- 1}{i }\;\;(i\to \infty)$$

The series will diverge because  $-\frac 1i $ has a constant sign and $ \sum \frac 1i $ is divergent.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ZhengxingXue This test is very useful. Think about it.